# How can I collect list with WebClient in Spring Boot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I want to collect data the following for an Object.

```
{
"success": true,
"symbols": {
"AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
"AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
"ALL": "Albanian Lek"
     }
}
```

Our object like this;

```
public class Currencies {
    public String success;
    public List<ExternalCurrency> currencyList;
}

public class ExternalCurrency {
    public String shortCode;
    public String name;
}
```

How can I collect JSON Data with WebClient in Spring Boot ?

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried use https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo . But it gave me two class the following

public class ExternalCurrency {
    @JsonProperty("AED") 
    public String aED;
    @JsonProperty("AFN") 
    public String aFN;
    @JsonProperty("ALL") 
    public String aLL;
}

public class Currencies{
    public boolean success;
    public ExternalCurrency symbols;
}

I don't want like this. Because maybe tomorrow i will add a new currency

Comment: final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("-----").build();

        final Currencies data= webClient.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(Currencies.class).block();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a model that matches the `WebClient` response:

```java
public class Response {
    public String success;
    public Map<String, String> symbols;
}
```

And use it as follows:

```java
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("-----").build(); 
Response response = webClient.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(Response.class).block();
```

Now all you need is to map the `Response` object to `Currencies`.

Additionally, you should definitely avoid using `block()`. It defeats the whole purpose of using WebFlux.

Comment: It's work for me, thanks :)

Comment: Great! If you feel like it, accept the answer so that others can easily find the solution to similar issues ;)